# Hive queries running very slow

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am tasked with installing and configuring a two node cluster to use as a proof of concept for Hadoop. The cluster contains one machine that is both a master and slave, and the other a slave. Both are installed on Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines with 16GB RAM.

So I was able to get Hadoop 2.4 installed on both machines, got hdfs, yarn, hive etc running successfully. My problem now is once I start to add larger files/more data, the queries are crazy slow.

select count(*) from programs for example. Programs contains 45000 rows for a total of about 2.5 MB. After initialization it takes only a few seconds to get the result. 
Now running the same query on another table containing almost 17 million rows, 3.6GB, takes significantly longer (As I know it should). If I run count(*), or and variation of it on this large table it takes variable amounts of time. The first time it takes 4 minutes. I run it immediately after the first finishes and it take 17 minutes. Nothing changes between runs, so I'm not sure what is going on. Often times during these long runs the machines will freeze and become unresponsive to any input. Map will remain at 0% for 5 mins, jump to about 30%, then slowly increase.

My question is: is this normal behaviour? I would expect the same job to have a consistent run time if I run it right away again. Perhaps there is an underlying issue with Ubuntu, I'm not sure. If I monitor CPU or disk usage during a job they are both never is crazy high territory so I'm not sure where it's getting hung up. Looking at log files doesn't show any exceptions. If a job is especially slow (getting upwards of 45 minutes), log files will show a bunch of SocketTimeoutExceptions.

I've played with different config options but nothing seems to really help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: Originally in csv format, tab delimited.

Comment: Hmm, tough to say if this behavior can be expected or not.  Have you looked at the job tracker logs (or application master if you're using MR/yarn)?

Comment: ... usually Hive CLI will tell you where you can track the status of a job right before it runs.

Comment: I can track the job progress on the web ui but often times it is too slow to use (each page takes several minutes to load). The biggest problem seems to be the time it takes for each task to actually start. Once I launch the job it can take up to 5 minutes where each task will just sit at 'NEW' in the web ui. Once it actually begins it's usually pretty quick.

Comment: Aswell, in both nodes datanode log file there are frequent lines such as this : Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 3632ms

Comment: Hi @lhoworko, if you have maintained any document on installation of hadoop,hive and yarn on two VM's, could you share the same please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not normal behavior.  In Hive I can process ~17 million points in less than a minute including time spent during map/reduce initialization.  I'll list out a couple of issues that might be contributing to your slow performance.

- Virtual machines are not ideal for Hadoop.  You want machines with dedicated,local storage since disk I/O is generally the largest performance bottleneck.
- You only have two machines (*and they're VMs...*) running all of the Hadoop services, including, but not limited to, master services such as *Resource Manager* (YARN), *Hive Server*, and *NameNode* (HDFS).  This doesn't leave much left for map/reduce tasks.

For reference - on our dev cluster we have 3 machines dedicated to these master services.  They do not run any map/reduce tasks and are not part of the distributed storage.

Hadoop certainly isn't the best or fastest option for every use case, but your sandbox cluster isn't really giving it much of a chance to shine.

Comment: Interesting, I had doubts that our current set-up was anywhere near adequate. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out, info online seems fairly sparse on the topic.